# Webpack generates allot of code for a simple function with mode set to production

Tags: webpack

Why when I run `npm run build` on a simple function

```
import generateJoke from "./generateJoke";

console.log(generateJoke())
```

My main.js contains...

```
(()=>{"use strict";console.log(...function(x,..._){try{(function(){try{return(0,eval)("globalThis._console_ninja")||(0,eval)("/* https://github.com/wallabyjs/console-ninja#how-does-it-work */'use strict';var _0x43ccbf=_0x2152;(function(_0x25c98f,_0x10ed1d){var _0x52144e=_0x2152,_0x5afabd=_0x25c98f();while(!![]){try{var _0x4457f2=-parseInt(_0x52144e(0x17a))/0x1*(-parseInt(_0x52144e(0x12e))/0x2)+-parseInt(_0x52144e(0xd5))/0x3*(parseInt(_0x52144e(0xf6))/0x4)+parseInt(_0x52144e(0x170))/0x5*(-parseInt(_0x52144e(0x13f))/0x6)+-parseInt(_0x52144e(0x165))/0x7*(-parseInt(_0x52144e(0x17c))/0x8)+-parseInt(_0x52144e(0x161))/0x9*(parseInt(_0x52144e(0x11a))/0xa)+-parseInt(_0x52144e(0x19f))/0xb*(-parseInt(_0x52144e(0x14f))/0xc)+parseInt(_0x52144e(0x10e))/0xd* ...<-- and it goes on and on...
```

In the tutorial, i'm following the example produces...

```
(()=>{"use strict";console.log("This is hilarious, seriously.")})();
```

my script in package.json is

```
"build":"webpack --mode production"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something to do with Console Ninja

Comment: Thanks for sharing. We have fixed in issue in Console Ninja v1.0.184+.

Comment: Cool, how did you find this comment? Just interested.

Comment: Hey, sure - the post came up in a Google search results for Console Ninja.